# Div to swipe elements inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, swipe

I'm trying to make a div to swipe dynamically content in a iframe. Well, i have the code for swipe and others functions working fine, i just need help to create a div that work like a glass over all others element to swipe it, you know?

Here is my code:
HTML

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div id="swiper">
    <main class="mdl-layout__content" id="main">
        <div id="slider">
            <iframe id="content"></iframe>
            <div class="left_hold"><img id="left_-1" onClick="slideMove(this)" class="left" src="Images/arrow_left.png"></div>
            <div class="right_hold"><img id="right_1" onClick="slideMove(this)" class="right" src="Images/arrow_right.png"></div>                
        </div>
    </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The content(html pages) is dinamically put in the iframe element. The div to swip is id="swiper".

CSS:

```
#swiper{ display: block;    height: 100vh;    border: none;    overflow: auto;}

iframe {
position: absolute;
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border: none;
overflow: auto;
}
```

JavaScript to Swip(It Works):

```
$(function() {
  //Enable swiping...
  $("#swiper").swipe( {
    //Generic swipe handler for all directions
     swipeLeft:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
        slideMove($(".right")[0]);
    },
      swipeRight:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
        slideMove($(".left")[0]);
    },
    //Default is 75px, set to 0 for demo so any distance triggers swipe
     threshold:0
  });
});
```

What happening is: the swipe move only works in a little space in top of my page(where the swiper div begin), but when i inspect the div element in my browser, it is showing in full page. Why it dont's work when i slide in others parts of this element?

Thx a lot!!!